# Extracting scores from GoogleNet

Tags: caffe

I would like to extract the scores from the GoogleNet network from caffe models but I don't quite understand which layers keep the scores.

I get:

```
Check failed: feature_extraction_net->has_blob(blob_names[i]) Unknown feature blob name loss3/top-5 in the network ./train_val.prototxt
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: This looks like you're trying to get top-5 accuracy from a trained model, rather than the scores themselves.  Can you be more specific about which meaning of "score" you need?

Answer (score 0):

The layer `loss3/top5` is an [Accuracy layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/accuracy.html). I will assume that this is want you meant by *scores*.

By default, you will have something like this

```
layer {
  name: "loss3/top-5"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "loss3/classifier"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss3/top-5"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  accuracy_param {
    top_k: 5
  }
}
```

If you want to have this layer in training, you can remove or comment out (`#`) the `include` section.